# How to create a Drop down menu in UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, ios5

I am implementing a UITableView based application. In that I have a tableview with list of input fields. At one cell I need to show a drop down menu. Is it possible to implement a drop down menu in UITableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it's possible, but not really what you should be doing.  I would use a UITableViewAccessoryDetailDisclosure control in your table cell and slide off to the selection screen using the navigation controller - most of the work is already done for you.

IF however, you did want to do a drop down in situ, then I would probably dynamically insert rows in the table view immediately following the row.  They would need to look different to you main table view cells, and you would need to delete them after a selection was made.  This is a lot of heavy lifting and I wouldn't go down this route.